# How do I partition data from a txt/csv file by year and month using Flume? Is is possible to make the HDFS path dynamic?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I want to configure a flume flow so that it takes in a CSV file as a source, checks the data, and dynamically separates each row of data into folders by year/month in HDFS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest you look at using [Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/) instead.  I feel like it's the natural replacement for Flume.

Having said that it would seem that you might want to consider using a the [spooling directory source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) and a [hive sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hive-sink) (instead of hdfs). The hive partitions (Partitions on year/Month) would enable you to land the data in the Manner you are suggesting.